# Setting nano as default editor not working for crontab with fish shell

Tags: fish

I want to set nano as default editor for crontab on my Mac.

This works:

```
VISUAL=nano crontab -e
```

but this don't work

```
set -U VISUAL nano
crontab -e
```

here still vim is used as default editor

```
ECHO $VISUAL
```

shows

```
nano
```

as value.

Any ideas where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set -U VISUAL nano` only sets the variable within Fish. If you want to make it visible also in binaries started by the shell you need to export it, e.g. by using `set -Ux VISUAL nano`.

For more details

- [Variable Scope](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#variable-scope)
- [Exporting Variables](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#exporting-variables)

Comment: thanks @nohillside this works for me